# How to save mustache template for rendering in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache

My data is in this format

```
let data = {"list" :[
                    {
                       "email": "abc@example.com",
                       "name": "abc",
                       "date": "05/01/2015"
                    },
                    {
                       "email": "xyz@example.com",
                       "name": "xyz",
                       "date": "05/01/2015"
                    } 
                  ]};
```

My mustache template is like this:

```
{{#list}}
Hii {{name}} your email is {{email}}
{{/list}}
```

I saved this template as .html file

In my main code I'm getting this html file as

```
const template = fs.readFileSync('./views/template.html', 'utf-8');

result = Mustache.render(template, data)
```

And I'm sending that result to a mail and I'm getting nothing in email instead of that template

Did I do anything wrong. Plz help me to solve this thing. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you output `result`? What does it contain?

Comment: Thanks for responding @Alex , I'm just sending an email of that template (result) to my mail. Nothing is printed in that mail.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is what the variable `result` contains _before_ you try to email it. That will clarify if the problem is actually with Mustache or your mail sending code. Add `console.log(result)` after the code you have above.

Comment: If i console the result, I'm getting it and i think there is a problem with my email and thanks..

Comment: @Alex, If i console the type of result as `console.log(typeOf(result))` I'm getting it as string, Is there no way to get it as html file, so that my mail seding function can send it as html file.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the code is right.

### Results

- For result

  Hii abc your email is abc@example.com

  Hii xyz your email is xyz@example.com
- For typeof(result)

  string

Can you post how you send the mail ? I suspect result is not used in your mail content ;)

### Tested with

- node@8.11.1
- npm@6.0.0
- mustache@2.3.0
- fs-extra@7.0.0